# Firebase.Functions.FunctionsException: UNAUTHENTICATED, Can't Call cloud function even after user is authenticated

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

Unity editor version: 2021.3.9f
Firebase Unity SDK version: 9.6.0
Source you installed the SDK: FirebaseFunctions(.unitypackage or Unity Package Manager)
Problematic Firebase Component: FirebaseFunctions
Other Firebase Components in use: FirebaseFunctions ,Auth
Additional SDKs you are using:
Platform you are using the Unity editor on: Windows
Platform you are targeting:Android
Scripting Runtime: IL2CPP
[REQUIRED] Please describe the issue here:
Firebase.Functions.FunctionsException: UNAUTHENTICATED
at Firebase.Functions.HttpsCallableReference.b__9_0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] task) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
I m trying to user firebase functions with unity. I have added firebase auth that is working perfectly. After auth I am calling my firebase function using this code below

`void FirebaseFucntionTest()
{

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Debug.Log("Calling");
FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance;
Debug.Log(FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.DisplayName);

var function = functions.GetHttpsCallable("testunity");
function.CallAsync(data).ContinueWith((task) =>
{
   if (task.IsFaulted)
   {
       foreach (var inner in task.Exception.InnerExceptions)
       {
           if (inner is FunctionsException)
           {
               var e = (FunctionsException)inner;
               var code = e.ErrorCode;
               var message = e.ToString();
               Debug.Log(message);
               Debug.Log(code);
           }
       }
   }
   else
   if (task.IsCompleted)
   {
       Debug.Log((string)task.Result.Data);
   }
});
```

}`

I am holding a reference to auth using: auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance; and after this I am calling my function that runs the cloud function, as you can see in the debug statement at the start of the method I getting the currentusername successfully, but after code moves to cloud function call it is giving me exception of unauthenticated: